# How to bulk insert 3 and more million records into Elastic Search using ASP.NET Core & ElasticClient Nest

Tags: c#, postgresql, elasticsearch, amazon-redshift, nest

I am facing problem while reading data from a Postgres database and inserting into Elastic search using Nest library in an ASP.NET Core console application.

My approach:

1. Get total rows from RedShift.
2. Make query of ~100,000 against RedShift.

   - Again divided the 100,000 rows into 10 ten times like 100,000/10,000
   - Make bulk insert into ES of ~10,000 records.
3. Make next query, offset +100,000.

It's working for 9 or 10 iterations, but sometime failed in ES.

Also this process is taking a long time, I am talking about only Elastic search insert time.

Errors:

> The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 60 seconds elapsing

> TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.

> IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..

> SocketException: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.

Could anyone help me to resolve this problem and tell me how we can insert 10+ million records into Elastic Search successfully?

Comment: **ASP.NET Core** is a web stack - a console application is **NOT** a web application - so really this is a **.NET Core** console app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unsure if the issue might be with anything else in your solution but this is what works for me:

```
var chunks = item.Items.Chunk(5000);

foreach (var chunk in chunks)
{
    await nestClient.BulkAsync(x => x.Index(item.Index).UpdateMany(chunk, (y, z) => y.IdFrom(z, true).Doc(z).Id(z.Id).RetriesOnConflict(2)));
}
```

You might want to check the reqiest timeout on you client, mine:

```
 ConnectionSettings settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)<other settings>.RequestTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3))
```

Comment: Can you explain me what this line will do await nestClient.BulkAsync(x => x.Index(item.Index).UpdateMany(chunk, (y, z) => y.IdFrom(z, true).Doc(z).Id(z.Id).RetriesOnConflict(2)));
And also I a question let say one document already exist in the index and when you will insert again same document then it will be duplicate the document ?

Comment: In my case I always upsert into ELK, hence UpdateMany. IdFrom will look for an elk Id and if it finds it will update that document, else insert the new doc. I also specify the index on insertion so that is done like this: x.Index(item.Index)

Comment: It is good when you want to just insert the record? becouse if I used your code that is inserting and updating both at a time it can be take more time compared to just insertion?

Comment: It depends on many things, and what you would like to achieve. I could manage upserts in the thousands per second, implementation is everything.

Comment: Where and how to manage the upserts, Can you give me an example related to my code

Comment: Hey, Your code snippet is works for me, I have just one question like I read 24,00,000 record from mySQL and insert 50,000 record per request it into Elastic Search, its successfully inserted without any error but when I seen on total Document count on Elastic search its showing only 22,55,593. Any idea why its insert only 22,55,593

Comment: Glad to hear, please mark as answer if correct. Try selecting district from your 50k SQL results to see if it matches up to the count you get from elastic, if you are upserting, it will only insert unique documents.

Answer (score 0):

Lower the size of the bulk, as 10000 may be too large. Usual size is 1000. It really depends on your hardware and the Elasticsearch cluster configuration, but clearly if you have issues, you should reduce the batch size.

Set the number of replicas to 0 and the refresh interval to -1 on your index when you are indexing. That way, Elasticsearch is fully dedicated to index your data, it does not spend resources replicating the data or merging the segments.

To update the number of replica :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#indices-update-settings

To update the refresh interval :
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#bulk

Comment: Could you suggest me how to set the number of replicas to 0 and refresh interval to -1 in my existing code that I shared here?

Comment: I don't know the Nest library.
By API, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html